# River Length within each cell of a grid r

Tags: r, distance, r-sf

I am trying to measure how many kilometers of river each cell of a grid contains.

My river shapefile is a single row shapefile (not one row for every river).

I have tried to modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993193/road-length-within-polygons-in-r) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280760/intersecting-lines-and-polygons-and-calculating-line-length-in-r) codes but have failed.

below is a description of the two objects

`> > grid5km Simple feature collection with 4075 features and 5 fields geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON dimension:      XY bbox:           xmin: 225320.3 ymin: 481277.6 xmax: 681165.7 ymax: 945385.3 epsg (SRID):    32629 proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=29 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs First 10 features: id      xmin      xmax    ymin    ymax                       geometry 0  28 -10.21953 -10.17431 8.50657 8.55179 MULTIPOLYGON (((369972.9 94... 1  29 -10.17431 -10.12909 8.50657 8.55179 MULTIPOLYGON (((370749.6 94...`

`> river Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field geometry type:  MULTILINESTRING dimension:      XY bbox:           xmin: 231870.6 ymin: 483505.6 xmax: 680763.9 ymax: 945087.4 epsg (SRID):    32629 proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=29 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs Strahler                       geometry 0        3 MULTILINESTRING ((232019.2 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not exactly reproducible, so allow me to continue with my example; note that it is built on a set of polygons (the standard North Carolina shapefile shipped with {sf} package) and a linestring object.

You find that your multilinestring object does not quite work; in such case consider `sf::st_line_merge()` to convert a multilinestring into a linestring (I have no way to check).

The key aspect is using `sf::st_intersection()` followed by `sf::st_length()`; the results will be in units of your CRS - in this example I am using a quaint local CRS (make furlongs great again...)

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# included with sf package
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  select(NAME) %>%  # just geometry, no data
  st_transform(crs = 6543)  # note: the result will be in US survey feet

# a slice of the 36th parallel
parallel36 <- st_linestring(matrix(c(-84, 36, -75, 36), 
                                   nrow = 2, byrow = T), 
                            dim = "XY") %>% 
  st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 6543)  # again, a quaint local projection

# overview of result
plot(st_geometry(shape), col = "grey50")
plot(parallel36, add = T, col = "red")
```

[image]

```
# this is where the action happens ...
xsection <- st_intersection(shape, parallel36)  %>% # cross section
  mutate(length = st_length(.)) %>%  # calculate length
  st_drop_geometry() %>%  # geometry is no longer required
  units::drop_units() # drop units denomination

# to add the data back to the shape object
shape <- shape %>% 
  left_join(xsection, by = c("NAME"))

plot(shape["length"])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jindra, this is what I was able to get from the codes I mentioned abode. Two points here I am trying to get. First how can I plut this back into my grid (shape in your example) so that my grid/shape have a new attribute (with 0 if polygon not crossed by river or parallel36) which is the length of river in the polygon/ or cell. Second I try to then export my dataframe to stata and it seems that your [US_survey_foot] (in my case [m]) is causing trouble to export. Hence is there a way to get the length without the unit? Thks!

Comment: hi @MarcelCampion - I have amended the answer slightly. To summarize my points you need to: 1) strongly consider dropping stata (just joking) 2) apply `units::drop_units()` to get rid of unwanted unit specification and 3) use the power of `dplyr::left_join()` to add the intersection length back to your shapefile; you will need a common key, like a key index or what not.

Comment: Hi Jindra Lacko, thanks for your code. It works perfectly. So what makes the difference from the two codes I used before is the `st_drop_geometry` and the `units::drop_units()`. About Stata... I know I should switch to r... Soon I will once my Stata licence expires ah

Comment: Glad to be of service, and please excuse my little dig; it was meant to be very light hearthed... :)